# Add n-word to "bad comment" word list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, comments

Some words in comments result in the comment being auto-deleted when a single (?) "rude" flag is cast. Please could we add the n-word to that filter?

Here are some examples from [a few moments ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38553093/560648) (censorship mine).

These were deleted very quickly, because of the f-word:

> F*** you, kill yourself @LightnessRacesInOrbit
>
> Keep deleting please, worthless n****r, f*** you.

However, this was not (and, at time of writing, the message remains visible):

> n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r n****r

… and an update from this very post, just to show that it's a problem on meta too:

> Why is the word n****r not 'okay'? F***ing racist n****r, f*** you.

Comment: Yes please, this particular word is always offensive, there is no context whatsoever that can make it 'okay'.

Comment: @Tunaki: Well, black rappers seem to think it's okay. But other than that, yes :)

Comment: There is a movement in certain circles to recapture the word from the oppressors and transform it into something positive. One of the few places where black hip-hop culture and liberal academia have some overlap. But they drop the "er" ending and replace it with "a". And it can still be offensive in the wrong forum.

Comment: @CodyGray: Multi-billion-dollar rappers don't seem terribly "oppressed". Meanwhile, if I were to attempt uttering the word in the same friendly context as employed in those songs, I would be vilified, and that's purely because of my race. So, until there is some equality or at least unambiguity, it's best to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Absolutely. Racists have to go off and be destroyed! Did I already mentioned they should be burned alive after torture?

Comment: I am surprised, you aren't even a*-american, as far I know. The poster probably didn't know the optimal strategy here. He had to contribute higher level posts.

Comment: Rappers are using it in an entirely different context. Regardless of wether that's OK or not I don't believe it's a good fit for any part of SO.

Comment: That's odd. I was pretty sure this and other slurs *were* on the one-flag-delete list. I swear I've seen them deleted before with a single flag. This (former) user kept re-posting the same comment the instant the previous one was deleted, so maybe it looked like these weren't being destroyed when they really were.

Comment: @BradLarson: Hmm, dunno, despite the repetition it didn't seem like it (timing, timestamps, etc) but maybe I missed it.

Comment: Arguably the most offensive thing about these messages is the repeated employment of _comma splices_ arggghhh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We try to use this list relatively sparingly, since it's easy to generate a lot of weirdness from [well intentioned bans on strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

That said, looking at the horrific history here, **blocking the n-word feels like a no-brainer**.  Barring some major surprise, we'll make this happen ASAP.

Comment: Cheers pal o' mine :)